# QML header id not available property

Tags: qt, qml

```
import Game 1.0

GridView {
    id: root
    model: GameboardModel{

    }
    header:
        Rectangle {
        id: headerId
        color: "lightgreen"
        height: 50
        Text{
            text: "header"
            color:"blue"
        }   
    }
    cellHeight: (height-headerId.height)/root.model.dimension
    cellWidth: width/root.model.dimension

}
```

How can i get property height from header? headerId.height doesn't work.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owlWc.png) displayes the problem. GameBoard is not filled by rectangles full.

On [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUN3K.png) example of correct behavior, work in this case (height-50)/root.model.dimension

Color of header is white, but in property color is set light-green. Why does white color display.

Comment: i have edited my question

images is linked in head of question

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a width and height for GridView and also width for the Rectangle header object.

Finally, instead of headerId, use root.header  to access it.

```
   import Game 1.0

    GridView {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        id: root
        model: GameboardModel{

        }
        header:
            Rectangle {
            id: headerId
            color: "lightgreen"
            height: 50
            width: parent.width
            Text{
                text: "header"
                color:"blue"
            }   
        }
        cellHeight: (height-root.header.height)/root.model.dimension
        cellWidth: width/root.model.dimension

    }
```

You could also create a property alias that points headerId to root.header in the root context

```
 GridView {

    property alias headerId: root.header
```